# What exactly is the director trying to express in the scene where Mia and Sebastian are flying through the stars?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, la-la-land

In the movie [***La La Land***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3783958/),  in the scene *(somewhere in the middle of the film)* where both Ryan and Emma are shown flying through the stars and galaxies.

What exactly is director Damien Chazelle trying to express?

I have a tad idea about it but would like to know more from you guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to a recent *IndieWIRE* interview with **Damien Chazelle** by **Anne Thompson** for *Thompson on the Oscars*, it was inspired by ***Mary Poppins***:

> [Next up, the ***La La Land*** crew are off to Paris to show the movie
>   to **Michel Legrand**, who wrote all the **Jacques Demy** music. They got a
>   kick out of meeting ***Mary Poppins*** songwriter **Richard M. Sherman**. That sequence of the couple dancing above the clouds against the
>   starry sky? It’s right out of ***Mary Poppins***.](http://www.indiewire.com/2016/12/la-la-land-oscars-emma-stone-damien-chazelle-interview-video-1201752529/)

Answer (score 2):

It is the cinematic realization of figures of speech for falling in love such as *lighthearted* and *head in the clouds* and *in their own (beautiful) world*.